# Adding a horizontal line between modules in same position in Joomla

Tags: php, css, joomla

I am working on developing a website using Joomla and a custom template, and I have a question.  I have assigned a module to the template's sidebar position, and that works great.  If I would then like to add a second module to that same sidebar, however, I would like a way to insert a horizontal line between them.  Can this be done using CSS, would I have to add to my index.php, or would I have to modify a core Joomla file?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks much in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to do this.

I would edit the top module and add a Module Class Suffix e.g. `horizontal-line` or similar.

Then [create or edit a custom CSS file](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3878/120) and add the border using CSS like this or similar:

```
.horizontal-line {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #888888;
}
```